# When frame is removed from DOM, does JS that was running inside gets cleared from memory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, dom

I have the 1 page app where the UI is handled on the main page, and the controllers and models are loaded in the invisible frame. At some point, those models and controllers should change, so I remove the frame, create a new frame with different controllers and models and let it control the UI on the main page.

So the question is, does the JS that was running inside of the frame gets cleared from the memory once the frame is removed from the DOM or am I looking at potential memory leak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the question is, does the JS that was running inside of the frame gets cleared from the memory once the frame is removed from the DOM or am I looking at potential memory leak?

The JS and such in the frame are *eligible* to be removed from memory when the last outstanding reference to them is released. So you could remove the frame from the DOM, but if you still have a reference to it (for instance, in a JavaScript variable in another frame/window), then it will remain in memory. Or if you still have variables in another frame/window that refer to objects created in the frame you're removing, they (but not necessarily the frame) will be kept.

If you don't have any variables left pointing at the frame or the things in it, and you remove it from the DOM, then it will be eligible for garbage collection. When that happens is browser-dependent, but it will happen.

Comment: So, if I make sure that the code in the frame talks to main page one way, and there's no reference from main page to the code in the frame, can I be sure that it will be cleared by garbage collector?

Comment: @shershams: Yes. Eventually (and probably fairly quickly).

Answer (score 2):

The browser manages its memory usage; any memory leak created by JavaScript is effectively a defect in the browser itself, particularly in a situation as you've described. The closest you can get to a "memory leak" in JavaScript is instantiating objects in a global scope that you don't continue to use; this should only impact long-running pages (dynamic web apps a la GMail, etc.)

Comment: You can assume that it's very long-running pages. I just don't want the browser to freeze up or worse - the global name conflicts. But since it's running inside of the frame, it's basically global to that frame, so I'd guess the garbage collector would clear it up pretty quickly. Am I wrong thinking this?

Comment: Removing the frame, barring any browser defects, will mark anything in the frame's scope for GC. As to when GC will remove it, that's up to the browser.